# How to use both $push & $set with findOneAndUpdate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const result = await Property.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body._id },
    {
      $set: body,
      $push: { property_photos: { $each: img } },
    },
    {
      new: true
    }
  ).populate({
    path: "posted_by",
    select: { email: 1 }
  });
```

**Currently, I am getting an error "Updating the path 'property_photos' would create a conflict at 'property_photos'".**
But, When I am using these standalone both are working fine.

And I don't want to use updateOne because I want updated document too in my response.
**So, How can I use both $set and $push with findOneAndUpdate?**

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I was passing "property_photos" in my body object also. So it was conflicting.

Comment: Even I am also facing the same issue. Can you elaborate on how you resolved it?

Comment: @bubble-cord What i was doing.....here in my code property_photos was array. So i also passing the property_photos in body - $set: body.
So i removed the property_photos from body and after that everything works fine.